# R shiny app sometimes plot the charts on half of the screen only, on refreshing it plots normally on full screen

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, width

I have a R shiny app in which I've plotted charts using plotly library, when I run the app, the charts are plotted shrunk. They are not plotted according to the width of the screen. Specifying width did not help. The issue occurs randomly and not always, and it resolves on refreshing the app.

[Image with normal plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T44aI.png)

[Image with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOJMt.png)

You can see the issue in the images attached above. Below is the code for reference:

```
output$plot1_5 <- renderPlotly({

      sp_list <- spread_price()
      sp_contract <- sp_list$Contract
      p01 <- fun_price_plot(sp_list$TU,"TU","Days Since First Notice",T,sp_contract)
      p02 <- fun_price_plot(sp_list$FV,"FV","Days Since First Notice",F,sp_contract)
      p03 <- fun_price_plot(sp_list$TY,"TY","Days Since First Notice",F,sp_contract)
      p04 <- fun_price_plot(sp_list$TN,"TN","Days Since First Notice",F,sp_contract)
      p05 <- fun_price_plot(sp_list$US,"US","Days Since First Notice",F,sp_contract)
      p06 <- fun_price_plot(sp_list$AUL,"AUL","Days Since First Notice",F,sp_contract)

      p <- subplot(p01,p02,p03,p04,p05,p06,nrows=2,margin=.02,shareX=F,shareY=F)

      return(p)
    })
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It looks like your plot is finished loading before the rest of the page. Unfortunately, Without any of your code, it isn't feasible to offer an actual solution. When asking questions about coding it's always best to include *code*.  It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: @Kat thanks for replying. I have edited the post and added the code. I hope now you would be able to understand the issue better.